# Contour plots for functions with flat regions

Tags: plotting

I'm playing around with some optimization functions and contour plot seems to be not very informative (full notebook [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/74af0d80-df78-48d0-b7c2-a5638b994de2) ). Any suggestions how to make them more visually informative?

```
n = 2;
e = 0.01;
cov = {{1, 1 - e}, {1 - e, 1}};
zero = 0 & /@ Range@n;
normal = MultinormalDistribution[zero, cov];
pdf[x_, y_] = PDF[normal, {x, y}];
ContourPlot[pdf[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]
The loss

```
dsize = 1000;
SeedRandom[0];
X = RandomVariate[normal, {dsize}] // Transpose;
w = {1, 1}
Y = Dot[w, X];
XY = X~Join~{Y};

loss[w_] := Module[{error},
   error = (w.X - Y);
   Norm[error]^2
   ];
plt1 = ContourPlot[loss[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> 100, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

For the last one I'm interested in seeing the contours around the minimum so that it's more clear that gradient descent is moving in the right direction

[image]

Comment: 1) Plot the logarithm of the function.  2) Use an informative color function, such as "Rainbow".

Comment: @David, [Rainbow is likely not the best colormap here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MCG.2007.323435). A rescaling of the independent variables might be suitable in this case.

Comment: For the first figure add in `PlotRange->All` to the `ContourPlot` function.